# Mike Ash Singleton: Placing @synchronized

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, double-checked-locking

I came accross this on the Mike Ash "Care and feeding of singletons" and was a little puzzeled by his comment:

> This code is kind of slow, though.
>   Taking a lock is somewhat expensive.
>   Making it more painful is the fact
>   that the vast majority of the time,
>   the lock is pointless. The lock is
>   only needed when foo is nil, which
>   basically only happens once. After the
>   singleton is initialized, the need for
>   the lock is gone, but the lock itself
>   remains.

```
+(id)sharedFoo {
    static Foo *foo = nil;
    @synchronized([Foo class]) {
        if(!foo) foo = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return foo;
}
```

My question is, and there is no doubt a good reason for this but why can't you write (see below) to limit the lock to when foo is nil?

```
+(id)sharedFoo {
    static Foo *foo = nil;
    if(!foo) {
        @synchronized([Foo class]) {
            foo = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return foo;
}
```

cheers gary

Comment: Ah ok, so basically you need a check inside the @synchronize block?

Comment: That’s the whole point of the @synchronized: Allow one thread at a time to make the check.

Comment: Try dispatch_once() instead: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5720029/290295

Comment: Here are some benchmarks comparing @synchronized "singleton" implementations vs. dispatch_once()  (dispatch_once wins handily) http://bjhomer.blogspot.com/2011/09/synchronized-vs-dispatchonce.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because then the test is subject to a race condition. Two different threads might independently test that `foo` is `nil`, and then (sequentially) create separate instances. This can happen in your modified version when one thread performs the test while the other is still inside `+[Foo alloc]` or `-[Foo init]`, but has not yet set `foo`.

By the way, I wouldn't do it that way at all. Check out the `dispatch_once()` function, which lets you guarantee that a block is only ever executed once during your app's lifetime (assuming you have GCD on the platform you're targeting).

Comment: That’s of course true. But wouldn’t the best solution be to test twice (inside **and** outside of the `@synchronized`). Then there would be no race condition nor performance penalty.

Comment: @Nikolai: tell me there's a performance penalty _after_ you've run Shark. :-)

Comment: @Graham: There’s no doubt that performance is bad in the original version that always takes the lock. I had it in my code *and I did run Shark* ;). Also, Mike Ash pointed it out in his original blog post.

Comment: Hi Graham, at the moment I am developing for the iPhone, so I really just wanted to understand what was happening.

Comment: @Nikolai: Mike doesn't always run Shark. But if performance is bad for you, how frequently are you accessing this singleton? Must be thousands of times a second or more to get any noticeable cost.

Comment: @Graham: In my case I searched a database of 800,000 records. In the hot loop, I accessed the database using the singleton pattern. Searching was twice as fast after moving the `[MyDB sharedDB]` out of the loop. I came to the conclusion that synchronization is really slow (at least on the arm platform I was using) and I looked for alternatives. Mike Ash (and @mfazekas below) explained, why double checked locking is no good idea.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html

Answer (score 7):

This is called the [double checked locking "optimization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). As documented everywhere this is not safe. Even if it's not defeated by a compiler optimization, it will be defeated the way memory works on modern machines, unless you use some kind of fence/barriers.

[Mike Ash also shows](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html) the correct solution using `volatile` and `OSMemoryBarrier();`.

The issue is that when one thread executes `foo = [[self alloc] init];` there is no guarantee that when an other thread sees `foo != 0` all memory writes performed by `init` is visible too.

Also see [DCL and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2423513) and [DCL and java](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) for more details.

Comment: +1 Thanks for making this clear. Instruction reordering and out-of-order memory access are both concepts that most programmers are not aware of.

Comment: dispatch_once is the real solution, just use that and quit hacking

Answer (score 1):

In your version the check for `!foo` could be occurring on multiple threads at the same time, allowing two threads to jump into the `alloc` block, one waiting for the other to finish before allocating another instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize by only taking the lock if foo==nil, but after that you need to test again (within the @synchronized) to guard against race conditions.

```
+ (id)sharedFoo {
    static Foo *foo = nil;
    if(!foo) {
        @synchronized([Foo class]) {
            if (!foo)  // test again, in case 2 threads doing this at once
                foo = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way if you have grand cenral dispatch

```
+ (MySingleton*) instance {
 static dispatch_once_t _singletonPredicate;
 static MySingleton *_singleton = nil;

 dispatch_once(&_singletonPredicate, ^{
    _singleton = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
 });

 return _singleton
 }
+ (id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
  return [self instance];
 }
```