# Update current location in all views from navbar locationButton

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

I have a custom navbar with a locateButton that is visible in every view

[image]

When a user taps the locateButton, I would like to update lat and long on every view. I've got it working in one view at a time, with the following code.

```
ViewController.m

- (UIBarButtonItem *)locateButton {
    [locationButton addTarget:self action:@selector(locationPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];       
} 

- (IBAction)locationPressed:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        latLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        longLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                                 placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea];
            addressLabel.numberOfLines = 0;



        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
```

I'm trying to add a singleton to accomplish this.

In Location.h

```
//  Location.h


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>



@interface Location : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager* locationManager;

+ (Location*)sharedSingleton;


@end
```

Then in Location.M

```
//  Location.m


#import "Location.h"

@implementation Location

@synthesize locationManager;


- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
        [self.locationManager setHeadingFilter:kCLHeadingFilterNone];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        //do any more customization to your location manager
    }

    return self;
}

+ (Location*)sharedSingleton {
    static Location* sharedSingleton;
    if(!sharedSingleton) {
        @synchronized(sharedSingleton) {
            sharedSingleton = [Location new];
        }
    }

    return sharedSingleton;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

@end

How do I get my `- (IBAction)locationPressed:(id)sender` in another view let's say `HomeViewController.m` to call this locationManager method and also update the singleton value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider a singleton as your location manager and location manager delegate. There are a bunch of stackoverflow questions about creating singletons like this one: [Singleton in iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796529/singleton-in-ios-5).

Then when your user clicks that button, your singleton class will be called and updated and other views will look at that same singleton to get their location info.

Comment: I've added my attempt at using a singleton and updated my question. I still need to figure out how to use the singleton in my - (IBAction)locationPressed:(id)sender method

Comment: You should be able to use your singleton anywhere in any .m file in the project. Wherever you want to use it, import it. #import "MySingleton.h" Then call it [[MySingleton sharedInstance] someMethod] if it doesn't already exist it will be created and if it does exist, the existing one will be used.