# How to declare an instance of UIImageView as global?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to use single imageview in all classes so i want to declare it as global. Can anyone please tell me how to declare it as global.

Comment: Is this to be used across multiple view controllers?

Comment: IMHO, you can attach the image view to [a singleton instance][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

you can create it in appdelegate and use it

```
 AppDelegate *localVar = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; // OK
    localVar.imageView=[...];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, you may use **Singleton Class**.

here the tutorial http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is something that really vibes with how iOS does things, but if you really want to, you can declare the variable as a forward declaration in some `.h` file:

```
extern something_t *x;
```

and then in a `.c` or `.m` file, actually define the variable:

```
something_t *x;
```

If you want to initialize it, you can place an initialization wherever you deem appropriate:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*) notice {
    x = [[Something_T alloc] init];
}
```

Again, not sure this is the right way to solve whatever problem you might be having. A singleton might be a more Cocoa-esque idea.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable in Yourapp_Prefix.pch file in the project. The file is located in 'other sources' group.

UIImageView *imgv;

Now you can access the object imgv in any class.