# should core data code must be embedded into viewController code

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm now developing an app with core data on iPhone. After reading many projects about core data, I find that core data code is embedded into viewController code in all of there projects. for example:

```
@interface MyAppMasterViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyAppDetailViewController *detailViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

I want to split all code about core data from viewController, and create a special storage class. what's more, provide some method to package core data api, for example:

```
@interface MyAppMasterViewController : UITableViewController
...
...
@interface MyAppStorageClass : NSObject <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

(Note *)createNote;
(BOOL)deleteNote;
```

I think, if one day, I don't want to use core data to store my project, I can replace it with low cost.

All above, is that right? and can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a good idea to separate your data storage code from your user interface code.  I tend to use a singleton class [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c) to manage data for an application.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to factor that out into a data access object. The code isn't spread around, easy testable (code coverage) and reusable even in other projects. Using a singleton and putting that into the appDelegate makes sense in most cases.