# How to persistant store twitter iOS5 ACAccount for use in mutiple view controllers

Tags: ios, twitter

i have completely implemented the twitter iOS5 account and assuming user has granted permissionin in the settings page.

I want use the same account in various views on the app but dont want to keep asking the user for granting access.

Is there a way to persistently store this?

Comment: This is what Appdelegate is for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several methods could be used here.

You could use a property on custom singleton class to hold onto and share the object.

This is a good pattern here - [Create singleton using GCD's dispatch_once in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c)

You could use the AppDelegate class and keep it as a property on the class but that pattern wise isn't so good IMHO as it treats the AppDelegate as a junk-yard for things you don't know what to do with and you also end up with ugly casts all over the place.

`((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).acaccountobject`

Technically the singleton and the AppDelegate are the same principal but as mentioned the AppDelegate is not a junkyard.

Comment: I couldn't store ACAccount object to singleton class I made.  I can store usual objects like NSArray on the singleton class, but somehow, ACAccount can't be stored.  You don't have any problems on that?

Comment: Are you declaring the property on the ACAccount object as strong?

Comment: Yes, like this on ARC.  @property (nonatomic, strong) ACAccount             *account;  Dont know why. :(