# How to keep single object with ARC mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to keep one single object in application, and do not release.

```
@implementation MyClass

    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    + (MyClass *)sharedInstance {
        if (!sharedInstance) {
            sharedInstance = [[super alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedInstance;
    }
@end
```

I can get single object by `[MyClass sharedInstance]`, it works well in Non-ARC mode.

But the object will release when change to ARC mode.

Comment: The code you have written here is correct, if not threadsafe. If the object is getting deallocated, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Make a Object of MyClass in AppDelegate.

Comment: Why are you calling `[super alloc]`? It should be `[self alloc]` or `[MyClass alloc]`. Also, why is `sharedInstance` static variable of type `MyClass` and the return type of the `sharedInstance` class method `Ap`? They need to be the same.

Comment: Sorry , I have solved it myself!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c for a better way to create a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it would release? You've assigned it to a static variable tracked by ARC.

Comment: The reason is not that the variable is declared `static`, but that its storage duration is static, same as all file scope variables. In this context `static` only means internal linkage.