# Best singleton pattern for thread safe object

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

Whats the best pattern for singleton? I frequently use

```
+ (SomeManager *)shared
{
    static SomeManager * _SomeManager = nil;
    if (_SomeManager) {
        return _SomeManager;
    }

    _SomeManager = [[SomeManager alloc] init];

    return _SomeManager;
}
```

**Is this thread safe? If not, hot to make it safe?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c

Comment: `NSLock` or `@synchronized` or `dispatch_once` or etc...

Comment: Keep in mind that "singleton" and "thread-safe object" are two *entirely* different things.

Comment: Lazy allocation of singletons, which usually represent a handful of bytes of memory, is a degenerate pattern. Allocate your singleton in +[SomeManger initialize], guaranteed to only be called once at class load time.

Answer (score 1):

Using an example from 
[Create singleton using GCD's dispatch_once in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c)

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Clear and simple. Google better next time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the GCD dispatch_once method...

```
+ (id) sharedSomethingManager
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceQueue;
    static SomethingkManager *somethingManager = nil;

    dispatch_once(&onceQueue, ^{somethingManager = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return somethingManager;
}
```