# how to play sound whenever I open my iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried this code but didn't work,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"paying with coins and bills" ofType:@"wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath]), &(soundID));
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

}
```

It will play only when i runs the xcode project.

My requirement is, in my ipad whenever open my app i need to play a sound. Please help me

Comment: where's this code located? Have you checked whether `soundPath` is `nil`?

Comment: it is located in ViewController.m.

Comment: You have a view controller called `ViewController`? Sweet... Anyway can you confirm this code gets executed when you launch the app?

Comment: this code will executed only one time when my app launch

Comment: If your device is turned "silent", this API will not play sound, honoring user decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to move your code to AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

this method will be called when your app become active, which may fit in your case.

Comment: several ways. You may create a singleton class to manage your sound play. whenever you want to play or stop the sound, just let your singleton to do it. Or you can move you sound code to you ViewController, and create a Bool and use KVO to observe this property. and in your applicationDidBecomeActive change this property. And when you move to another viewController from the current viewController, just also change the property

Comment: can you explain with code for this.  Because i'm new to objective c

Comment: a singleton may be easier and clearer in this case. First, create a singleton (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c). Second, move your play and stop code to this singleton. Third, whenever you want to control the sound play, just call the singleton instance to do the operation.