# Sharing an NSDateFormatter between NSTextFields in view-based NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdateformatter, nstableview, nstextfield

I've searched high and low for the answer to this, but alas, I'm here. As I know that `NSDateFormatter` objects are costly to create, I don't want to instantiate one for every `NSTextField` inside of my table. The problem I'm facing is that my table is view-based (as opposed to cell-based), and when attempting to connect a shared instance of a date formatter, I get the yellow warning symbol and this message:

> Unsupported Configuration: Outlet 'formatter' of 'Text Field Cell -
>   Table View Cell' is connected to 'Date Formatter,' an invalid
>   destination (Objects inside view based table views may only be
>   connected to the table view's delegate.)

The problem with that warning is this: the above referenced "Date Formatter" is a property of "File's Owner," which also happens to be the `NSTableView`'s delegate. Am I missing something here, or am I going to have to create formatters for every date-related text field in my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach a shared formatter programmatically instead of in the xib file.  In your delegate method for returning the view for the cell, supposing that your cell class is `MyCellView` and `MyCellView` has a property `theTextField`, and the view is loaded from a xib file named `MyCellView.xib`:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    MyCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyCellView" owner:self];
    [result.theTextField setFormatter:[[self class] sharedFormatter]];
    return result;
}
```

Then you need this `sharedFormatter` method.  The `sharedFormatter` method will set up a lazily initialized singleton.  This is a pretty common pattern in iOS and Mac OS X development, and it's a good one to learn if you haven't seen it before:

```
+ (NSFormatter *)sharedFormatter {
    static NSFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSFormatter alloc] init];
        /* Set up the formatter's attributes here */
    });
    return formatter;
}
```

So `sharedFormatter` initializes its static `formatter` variable at most once (the first time the `sharedFormatter` method is called).  The `dispatch_once` causes all the code in its input block to be executed only one time, and even takes care of synchronizing calls occurring on multiple threads (though I doubt you'd be calling `sharedFormatter` from multiple threads).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! And actually, that's almost exactly what I tried doing after I posted this. The only difference being, instead of a class method, I was using an instance method without the `dispatch_once` call. I'll update my question above with my latest "issue."

Comment: Scratch everything I just said. It worked. I had a date formatting issue. It's always the little things that break everything. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

you should not creat formatters for every date-related text field .use Singleton can work it out.

add this code to your viewController

```
    + (NSDateFormatter *)sharedDateFormatter
    {

        NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
        static dispatch_once_t once;
        static NSDateFormatter * _sharedDateFormatter;

        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            _sharedDateFormatter  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        });
        return _sharedDateFormatter;


    }
```

,then you can access the NSDateFormatter Instance like this：

```
    [[self class] sharedDateFormatter]，or ['Your ViewController class ' sharedDateFormatter]
```

you can add a property to your date-related textfield ,call this method to set the NSDateFormatter Instance into textfield:

```
    yourTextField.dateFormatter =  ['Your ViewController class ' sharedDateFormatter];
```

it will only creat one NSDateFormatter instance ,if you don`t understand ,please read this:

[Create singleton using GCD's dispatch_once in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks for your response, too. I implemented the class formatter, but I'm still not getting output in the cell. It's just blank. Any ideas? P.S. See my updated question to see where I'm at.

Comment: Edit: I figured it out. Thanks for your response though.