# Could `dispatch_once` created singleton got released? If so, how to deal with it?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

As mentioned in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c), `dispatch_once` is very useful in building singleton. However, could `dispatch_once` created instance got released and `dispatch_once` was not able to created that instance because it only execute once?

If so, what is the best practice to deal with it?

Comment: "what is the best practice to deal with it?" Making sure your object doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: And how exactly would this singleton get released?

Comment: @CrimsonChris that is my first question, could singleton get released by ARC? Or it is a feature of singleton, that it will never get released?

Comment: If the reference to your singleton is static. It shouldn't ever be released unless you redirect the reference. Of course, the operating can sometimes do weird stuff in low memory situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

First best practice is generally going to be to avoid the singleton in the first place.

You can also use the `@synchronized(self)` pattern in place of the `dispatch_once` pattern to guarantee only a single object exists at one time, but that it can be re-instantiated if it is ever deallocated for any reason.

You could also reset your `dispatch_once` variable in dealloc, I think

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question with a second a part. Is there any solution to deal with it?

Comment: You could throw an exception in your singleton's dealloc method, so that if anyone accidentally releases that object, the program will crash immediately and let them know they messed up.

Comment: @Daiwei First best practice is generally going to be to avoid the singleton in the first place.  You can also use the `@synchronized(self)` pattern in place of the `dispatch_once` pattern to guarantee only a single object exists at one time, but that it can be re-instantiated if it is ever deallocated for any reason.  You could also reset your `dispatch_once` variable in `dealloc`, I think.

Comment: Thank you, if you want to include your comments in your answer, please do, as I update the question, and including comments explained the situation better.

Comment: Throwing an exception in `dealloc` is the worst idea I've heard all week.

Comment: @nhgrif Hi, why is it bad to throw exception in `dealloc` and what would be the alternative way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Unheilig The answer to that question isn't compact enough to fit in comments, and the question itself is opinion based so wouldn't be a good fit for StackOverflow.  The alternatives are outlined in my answer.  You could re-ask the question here and I'll gladly give my opinion on the matter: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12918/nschat