# How to create straight forward Singleton classes in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I am used to `Java` and currently on the process of learning `Objective-C`.

Basically I would create `Singleton` classes in `Java` like this:

```
public class SingletonClass{
  private static instance; //Step 1

  public static SingletonClass getInstance(){ //Step 2
    if(instance == null)
      instance = new SingletonClass();

    return instance;
  }
}
```

Very straightforward right?

But I find a hard time creating straight forward solution for that in `Objective-C`

I did like this:

```
@implementation SingletonClass(){
  //I want to do step 1 here which is to make a private static instance;
  //it is said that private variables are declared here
  static SingletonClass *instance; //but it is said that static keyword is different here
}

//then I would do something like step 2
+ (id)getInstance{
  if(instance == nil)
    instance = self;

  return instance;
}

@end
```

The problem is that there is an error :`Type name does not allow storage class to be specified`

**How do you guys make straight forward Singleton classes in Objective-C?**

Comment: Google. http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/singletons.html

Comment: If you dont like that one there are a bunch more.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c?rq=1

Comment: @cabellicar123, show anything you want there I am interested btw

Comment: Nice link you got there @rmaddy, Thanks!

Comment: It was from the list of related questions to the right. Those would have also appeared before you even submitted your question. It's always a good idea to review those before posting. :)

Comment: That Java singleton you made isn't thread safe. If the singleton creation has side effects, that can result in some hard to reproduce race conditions.

Comment: then can you please show us the **Correct** way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dispatch_once_t`:

From Apple docs [dispatch_once(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html)
The dispatch_once() function provides a simple and efficient mechanism to run an initializer exactly once, similar to pthread_once(3).

Also see: [Secrets of dispatch_once](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html) by Mike Ash

```
+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm new here in Objective-C, can you please explain about `dispatch_once_t`? Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer. Sorry for the late response by the way, I had to read your given links.

Comment: also want to give credits to @rmaddy's comment since his link (stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/…) was helpful

Answer (score -3):

They are called external variables in objective c.

In app delegate under #import put

```
NSString *singleton;
```

Then in what ever class (view controller) you want to use it in's .h file

```
extern NSString *singleton;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with creating a singleton.