# Init Method in Singleton Class (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, instance, init

I have a question regarding the safe way of implementing a singleton class in Objective-C. 
My background is mostly in web-development (PHP) but I know that in Obj-C things are quite different. For instance I have this custom class MyClass that I want to be singleton:

```
static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;

@interface MyClass:NSObject
    NSMutableArray *someArray;
@end

@implementation MyClass:NSObject

-(id)init
{
    if(sharedInstance) {
        self = sharedInstance;
    } else if((self=[super init])) {
        sharedInstance = self;
        someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    }

    return self;
}

+(MyClass *)sharedObject
{
    if(!sharedInstance) {
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc]init];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

1. It's ok this implementation?
2. Since in Obj-C I can't make the constructor private (as far as I know, maybe I'm wrong), it's ok this way of creating the init method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link [Create singleton using GCD's dispatch_once in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720029/create-singleton-using-gcds-dispatch-once-in-objective-c?rq=1) for the recommend approach to creating a singleton.

Using gcd, the code becomes thread-safe. Most people now consider the case that someone calls [[Singleton alloc] init] a bug that you wouldn't write code for, so the init method should just initialise the object.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. Indeed, I was thinking how to "disable" alloc/init.

Answer (score 2):

As [gnasher729](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28377590/793428) states, you need to use `dispatch_once_t` for the sake of thread safety.

```
+(MyClass *)sharedObject
{
    static MyClass *sharedObject = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
        sharedObject.someArray [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    });
    return sharedObject;
}
```

Comment: If I want to use `someArray` in other method for this class, how would I use it ?

Comment: just add below line of code into your singleton class.                                                                             - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
   retun [self sharedObject];
}