# How do I test that my NSNumberFormatter is only initialized once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, cocoa, singleton

I created a category for `NSDecimalNumber` in which I take an `NSString` and return a `NSDecimalNumber`. I'm using it in a few of my view controllers and wanted to create a single global instance of `NSNumberFormatter`. I think this works but I have no idea on how to test it. For example, I want to NSLog every time an `NSNumberFormatter` instance gets allocated. How do I do that?

```
#import "NSDecimalNumber+amountFromTextField.h"

@implementation NSDecimalNumber (amountFromTextField)

static NSNumberFormatter *nf;

+(NSDecimalNumber *)amountFromTextField:(NSString *)amount {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (nf == nil) {
            nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        }
    }
    NSDecimal _amount = [[nf numberFromString:amount] decimalValue];
    return [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:_amount];
}

@end
```

Comment: Use dispatch once. By this, the number formatter will be initialised only once. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5720029/3882338

Comment: That would still need to be tested, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the formatter allocation into another method, and assert on that:

```
+ (NSNumberFormatter*)amountFormatter;

- (void)testOnlyOneFormatterIsCreated {
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter1 = [NSDecimalNumber amountFormatter];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter2 = [NSDecimalNumber amountFormatter];
    XCTAssertEqual(formatter1, formatter2, "Expected only one formatter to be created");
}
```

The problem with your current implementation is the fact you don't have access to the created formatter, thus it very hard to test it. Splitting  object creation and business logic into separate units is also good for your code, as it keeps your units short and focused on one task only.